# What is the meaning of || (double vertical bar) in this KL divergence equation?

Tags: notation, kullback-leibler

What is the meaning of the || in this equation? I haven't been able to find it from googling.
[image: double bar example]

It's from page 8 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.05908.pdf

Thanks!

Comment: It is just a designation. Just read as KL divergence between $Q(z)$ and $P(z|X)$. Double bar for some reason is often involved in it, and why it is here is another good question I don't know answer to.

Comment: Some info on origin is at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1597380/origin-of-the-notation-for-statistical-divergence

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My understanding is that the double bar emphasises that the *order* of the arguments matters. The reminder is perhaps helpful because KL is used much like a distance, but it's not symmetric, so it's not a distance. The double bars don't actually *mean* something special over and above, say, a comma.